# Go Ethereum encode types.Transaction as hex

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I have a `types.Transaction` object.

How can I encode this to receive the raw transaction hex?

Something like this:

```
0xf305d719000000000000000000000000a6331220bfb0b1ad6ff6bea2b983fa15375dd1f1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003b9aca00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001dcd65000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000b63d434fafc6240e928928f27cdfcec90eba69d60000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061f4d7e8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Transaction.MarshalBinary](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types#Transaction.MarshalBinary) to obtain the rlp encoded raw transaction and then use [common.Bytes2Hex](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common#Bytes2Hex) to create the hex string.